# How do I display fetched data from an API by my SearchBar component in another component that doesn't have the same parent?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, fetch-api

I have a component called SearchBar:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import './SearchBar.css'

interface SearchBarProps {
  onSearchResults: (results: any[]) => void
  currentPage: string
}

const SearchBar: React.FC<SearchBarProps> = ({
  onSearchResults,
  currentPage,
}) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState<string>('')

  const handleSearch = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const apiEndpoint =
      currentPage === 'homepage'
        ? `http://localhost:5050/homepage/search/${query}`
        : currentPage === 'movies'
        ? `http://localhost:5050/movies/search/${query}`
        : currentPage === 'series'
        ? `http://localhost:5050/series/search/${query}`
        : null

    if (!apiEndpoint) {
      console.error('Invalid current page')
      return
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json()
  
        if (typeof onSearchResults === 'function') {
          onSearchResults(data)
        } else {
          console.error('onSearchResults is not a function')
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Error fetching data')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSearch} className="searchBox">
        <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
          <input
            name="search"
            type="search"
            className="form-control searchInput"
            id="search"
            placeholder={`Search ${
              currentPage === 'homepage' ? 'films, series' : currentPage
            }`}
            aria-label="Search"
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="form-control searchButton"
            id="submit"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBar
```

I want to display the data that's being fetched above, in this below component :

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchContainer from '../Navbar/SearchContainer'

interface SearchResult {
  title: string
  overview: string

}

interface SearchResultsSectionProps {
  results: SearchResult[]
}

const SearchResultsSection: React.FC<SearchResultsSectionProps> = ({
  results,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="search-results-section">
      <h2>Search Results</h2>
      {results.length > 0 ? (
        <ul>
          {results.map((result, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <p>Title: {result.title}</p>
              <p>Overview: {result.overview}</p>
           
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No results found.</p>
      )}

      <SearchContainer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchResultsSection
```

The first component called SearchBar is not found within the same parent component as the second component called SearchResultsSection. The component called SearchResultsSection is display within another component.
Furthermore, it seems that the function I'm trying to use isn't valid
The console log keeps telling me that the function OnSearchResults does not exist...

Comment: Where do you render SearchBar?

Comment: SearchBar is rendered inside my navbar component (Navbar.tsx)